# Can't find child control in template

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, code-behind

I have a control like this:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:MyControl}}}">
<telerik:RadComboBox 
    x:Name="radComboBox1"
    Margin="0,5,5,5">
    <telerik:RadComboBox.Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadGridView
                        x:Name="radGridView1"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding GridItemsSource}"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGridItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    </telerik:RadGridView>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </telerik:RadComboBoxItem.Template>
        </telerik:RadComboBoxItem>
    </telerik:RadComboBox.Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

When I try to access child control radGridView1 like

```
Dim item = radComboBox1.Items(0) 
Dim gr As RadGridView = item.Template.FindName("radGridView1", item)
```

gr is null

why can't it find radGrid1 in comboboxItem ?

Thanks

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, use DataBinding instead of procedural code.

Comment: I think you need to call `ApplyTemplate()` on radComboBox1 first.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in my answer that I linked from your last question...:

```
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)control.Template.FindName("Address", control);
```

... `control` was an actual control and not a data item like you'd get from `ComboBox.Items`. You can get the actual `ComboBoxItem` from your data item using the [`ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
ComboBoxItem control = radComboBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
```

Then you can access the `ControlTemplate` generated item from that.

Comment: ...But you should be using DataBinding instead.. (don't forget to mention it ;))

Comment: Haha... yes mate... I saw that you had already done that though. :)